# Google account gets suspended when using Gmail API from Node.js Nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, gmail-api, nodemailer

I have an Express web application on a Node.js server. It supports sending email notifications for registration, password reset, etc. For this, I use Nodemailer and XOAuth2 to connect to Google API using a normal Google account. The connection works well and emails are being sent as expected. But after a while (1-3 days), Google sends me a message saying my account "has been suspended because of a violation of our Terms of Service" [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pujg.png). So I have to manually recover the account using the link in the notification and then the emails that were blocked during suspension are sent.

- After getting 3 of those notifications, I noticed that they follow only if I triggered my email sending function (see below)
- I tried to log XOAuth2's token refresh and seems like it works
- I tried to renew the refreshToken from the playground several times but the problem remains

IMHO, it might be that I'm using a free account and Google wants me to pay for using its API, it thinks I do some kind spams, or it just doesn't want me to use its API. I'm I wrong?

So my questions are:

- Why does my account get suspended?
- What can I do to fix this problem?

Code details (approximate):

```
var bluebird = require('bluebird');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var xoauth2 = require('xoauth2');

// clientId, clientSecret taken from: https://console.developers.google.com/
//  Create credentials > OAuth client ID > Web application > 
//   Name = Nodemailer, 
//   Authorised redirect URIs = https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground
// 
// refreshToken taken from: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/
//  Access token location: Autorization header w/ Bearer prefix
//  Access type: Offline
//  Force prompt: Consent Screen
//  Use your own OAuth credentials: yes
//  Authorized APIs: everything inside Gmail API v1
//  Auto refresh the token after it expires: yes
xoauth2Gen = xoauth2.createXOAuth2Generator({
    user: 'example@gmail.com', // my real google account
    clientId: '84037...t.com', // my real clientId
    clientSecret: 'c3Yo...KP', // my real clientSecret
    refreshToken: '1/ex...Wk'  // my real refreshToken
    // nothing more here
});

var mail_transport: {
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: { xoauth2: xoauth2Gen }
};

var mailer = bluebird.promisifyAll(nodemailer.createTransport(mail_transport));

mailer.sendMail({
    from    : '"Example User" <example@gmail.com>',
    to      : 'recipient@gmail.com',
    subject : 'Example subject',
    text    : 'Example\nplain\ntext',
    // could it be bad html?
    html    : 'Example<br><strong>html</strong><br>version'
}).then(function (info) { console.log(info); });
```

Comment: Maybe someone found a way to exploit your service to send a large number of emails.

Comment: I don't think it's the case, and there aren't that many mail in my sent box. But thanks a lot

Comment: Have you checked if you exceeded any of the limitations when using Gmail API given in [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota)?

Comment: @Teyam Thanks for reminding me. My account could not have exceeded any limits. There were only 9 emails sent on September 3rd. And according to the link, exceeding limits should not suspend my account.